# Avoid access denied page after user logout

Tags: 7, redirection

I am using Drupal 7. It is good that when user is logged out and again he access the

```
user/logout
```

link he is redirected to **Access denied** page.

Now I want that instead of **Access denied** page, i want to redirect to the specific page.

Can i achieve it using [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module or i have to write the code for that

Comment: rules module will do

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In Site `Configuration > System > Site information` you can specify the Access denied path.

Simply give the path to your front page and you will be redirected to front page of the site.

Comment: Why is this even an answer?  You effectively take away your access denied page...  You can use rules and use the event on user logout.  Way better option IMO.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something called 403 redirect to Login:
https://drupal.org/project/r4032login

403 access denied messages will get redirected to the login page. I've used this before and it works nicely.

Comment: r4032login doesn't deal with logout

Comment: Not sure what Druvision is talking about-- this worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use Rule Module
Event   Operations: User has logged out

Actions Elements  Click add action Select the action to add "page redirect"

Here in url specify path where you want user after logout.e.g if you want to redirect to your site front page enter.
http://www.example.com
Note:replace example with your site name.

Answer (score 0):

For redirect choose "Page Redirect" in "System" options group

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating this logout link use the following to generate it and redirect the user.

```
l(t('Logout'), 'user/logout',array('query' => array('destination' => 'node/any')));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [redirect_after_logout](https://drupal.org/project/redirect_after_logout) module deals with it.